# Grant access to view.officeapps.live.com

Tags: ip, office365

When I use office online view service provided by microsoft, I want to just open my document to micorsoft (https://view.officeapps.live.com/op/view.aspx?src=newteach.pbworks.com%2Ff%2Fele%2Bnewsletter.docx), so I need to know all the IP addresses that need to access my document in this process. How can I get them? And does it work if the document url doesn't use the default 80 port? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I give up to directly grant access to view.officeapps.live.com, instead I upload my document to cloud and return a temporary url with token which is opened to public within 2 hours. the cloud service I used is Aliyun OSS and AWS also provides such service. Hope it helps!